# Does the Amasis font still exist, and how can I implement it?

Tags: fonts

I was wondering if the Amasis MT font is still available for use in LaTeX documents, and if so how can I use it for a short section of text in a document alongside Computer Modern? It seems to have the code "a2" but the command

```
\fontseries{a2}\selectfont
```

does nothing it seems.

Comment: It can be purchased in Open Type format, at least: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/amasis/

Comment: it would be `\fontfamily` not `\fontseries` (which is for things like bold) but if you mean this font https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/amasis it appears to be not free, and available as opentype so more easily used in xetex or luatex than pdftex

Comment: How would I go about installing the opentype file once obtained with texworks?

Comment: @wrb98, you install it in your system. Nothing to do with TexWorks. You use it with xetex or luatex. I'll spare you comments about the beauty or suitability of the font, though.

Comment: this isn't an ams font, so i have removed the `[amsfonts]` tag.